# Generating the symmetric group $S_n$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

I know that $\sigma =(1 2 \ldots n)$ and $\tau =(1 2)$ together should generate the symmetric group by virtue of conjugation, i.e.

$(\sigma)^k \circ \tau \circ (\sigma^{-1})^k = (k+1, k+2)$; we know that the set of adjacent transpositions generates $S_n$, so we're done.

However-- and I realize that this question is incredibly dumb-- when I try this for $n=3$, I should have that $\sigma \circ \tau \circ \sigma^{-1} = (2 3)$. But I get

$\sigma \circ \tau = (1 2 3) \circ (1 2) = (2 3)$ when I work it out by hand, writing out the digits and physically switching them; then $(2 3)\circ \sigma^{-1}= (1 3)$. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I'd confused sigma and tau. I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: $(\sigma\circ \tau)[x] = \sigma(\tau[x])$, so $((123)\circ(12))[1] = (123)[(12)[1]] = (123)[2] = [3]$. You fed in the argument from the wrong side. (Also, you confused $\sigma$ and $\tau$ at some point. With $\tau = (12...n)$, $\sigma^k\circ\tau\circ \sigma^{-k}$ is an $n$-cycle.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Please NOTE:** the answer below was written based on the original post: $$\sigma = (12), \;\tau = (123 \cdots n)$$

The original  post has now been edited.

When composing $\sigma\circ \tau \circ \sigma^{-1}$, we can first compose $\alpha = \tau \circ \sigma^{-1}$, and then compose $\sigma(\alpha)$. (Or else first compose $\sigma \circ \tau = \beta,$ and then compose $\beta(\sigma^{-1}).$

In your case $\tau\circ \sigma^{-1} = (123)(12) = (13)$, and then $\sigma\circ(\tau\circ \sigma^{-1}) = (12)(13) = (132).$

And as Daniel Fischer points out, you seem to have confused yourself when you conclude

> $$(\sigma)^k \circ \tau \circ (\sigma^{-1})^k = (k+1, k+2)$$

In fact, with $\tau = (1 2 3 \cdots n)$, we have that $\sigma^k\circ \tau \circ \sigma^{-k}$ must then be an $n$-cycle, as is $\tau$.

Comment: @Thomas: My point wasn't about the order of composition. I edited to make this clear. Thanks.

Comment: @Thomas: perhaps I'll hire you as my editor! ;-)

Comment: In that case, how do we generate the adjacent transpositions via conjugation? (I'd confused sigma and tau. THe question's a bit different now.)

Comment: Jonah, $\sigma = (12)$, $\tau = (123\cdots n)$ generates all of $S_n$ by virtue of the fact that all permutations in $S_n$ can be gotten by composition of powers of $\sigma$ and $\tau$.

Comment: Right, but as per my original question, what am I doing wrong when I say that $\sigma \circ \tau \circ \sigma^{-1} = (1 3)$?

Comment: You are failing to correctly compose $\sigma \tau \sigma^{-1}$. $\quad \tau\circ \sigma^{-1} = (123)(12) = (13)$, and then $$\sigma\circ(\tau\circ \sigma^{-1}) = (12)(13) = (132).$$