# Minimal generation of $S_n$

Tags: group-theory

For a given $n$, the [symmetric group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_group) $S_n$ is generated by permutations $p_1$, $p_2$, and $p_3$.  Two of them generate subgroups $P_{23}$, $P_{13}$, $P_{12}$, which have group orders $a$, $b$, and $c$.

What is the minimal $max(a,b,c)$ for various $n$?

Comment: The title is perhaps misleading. Of course, the minimal number of generators for $S_n$ is equal to $2$, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/711018/generating-the-symmetric-group-s-n?rq=1).

Comment: Certainly $2n$ is possible. Take $p_1=(2~n)(3~n-1)(4~n-2)\cdots$, $p_2=(1~n)(2~n-1)(3~n-2)\cdots$ and $p_3=(1~n)$. These generate the whole symmetric group ($p_1p_2=(1~2~3~\cdots~n)$ which is well known to generate everything with $p_3$). They are all involutions so, pairwise, they generate dihedral groups of order twice the order of the respective products, so we get that $\{a,b,c\}=\{4,6,2n\}$.

I'd be curious to know if a sub-linear or even constant bound is possible, for large $n$.

Comment: I did a quick (and really inefficient) computer check, and I think the values for n in [1..8] are [1,2,6,6,8,8,10,8]. This is not in the OEIS. Also, the fact that it is not monotonic suggests that it might be  hard to compute exactly. On the other hand, it does seem to be significantly below 2n. Also, I think in all extremal cases starting at n=4, the permutations were involutions.

Comment: There is certainly a constant bound. For example the result in http://www-circa.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/~tara/proof42.pdf shows that it is at most $84$ for all sufficiently large $n$ and I would guess that you can do better than that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is $8$ for all $n$ with $8 \le n  \le 26$ (as verret observed, it is $10$ for $n=7$), and I conjecture that it is $8$ for all larger $n$, with $S_n$ being a quotient of $$\langle x,y,z \mid x^2=y^2=z^2=(xy)^4=(yz)^4=(xz)^4=1 \rangle.$$

(It is possible that this is a known result.)

There are lots of solutions. Here are some for $n=6,7,8,9$ as requested.

$$n=6: (1, 2)(3, 4)(5, 6),\ 
    (1, 2)(3, 6),\ 
    (2, 3),$$

$$n=7: (1, 7)(2, 4)(5, 6),\ 
    (1, 2),\ 
    (1, 7)(2, 3)(4, 6),$$

$$n=8: (1, 8)(2, 3)(6, 7),\ 
    (1, 7)(2, 4)(3, 5),\ 
    (1, 2),$$

$$n=9: (1, 2)(3, 4),\ 
    (2, 4)(5, 6)(7, 8),\ 
    (3, 5)(4, 7)(6, 9).$$

Comment: Wow. Could you list the permutation sets for n=6 to 9?  Anything tricky about n=27?

Answer (score 4):

Derek Holt told me about this question yesterday evening.

The answer is 8 for all $n > 7$, because

(1) for every such $n$, the symmetric group $S_n$ is a smooth quotient of 
the $[4,4,4]$ Coxeter group 
$\langle \, a,b,c \ | \ a^2 = b^2 = c^2 = (ab)^4 = (bc)^4 = (ca)^4 = 1 \,\rangle$, and

(2) for every triple $(r,s,t)$ of integers with $1 \le r \le s \le t \le 3$, 
the $[r,s,t]$ Coxeter group 
$\langle \, a,b,c \ | \ a^2 = b^2 = c^2 = (ab)^r = (bc)^s = (ca)^t = 1 \,\rangle$ 
is finite, except in the case where $(r,s,t) = (3,3,3)$, when it is 
Euclidean and therefore soluble.

(Note: in (1) above, "smooth" means that the orders of $a, b, c, ab, bc$ and $ca$ are preserved in the quotient.)

Fact (1) above is not difficult to prove using coset diagrams.
One construction for each of the four residue classes of $n$ mod 4 
does this for all $n > 14$, and then an easy computation in {\sc Magma}
shows the same for $n = 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13$ and $14.$